# How can you programatically bind a Double to a WidthProperty?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, double

Can a `double` or `int` be bound to a `WidthProperty` of an element such as a `Button` or `Border`?

I have something like this but it does not seem to work. Maybe it's not the `Value` property that the binding needs.

```
double changedNum = 3;
double myWidth = 100 * changedNum;
border1.SetBinding(WidthProperty, new Binding("Value") { Source = myWidth });
```

*Update*

I have posted an answer to my question. My goal was to bind an existing slider value and multiply or divide by a double. Then have that value set as binding for another object's WidthProperty. Solution is below.

Comment: You cannot bind to a field or a local variable. myWidth needs to have an accessible getter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create a `Slider` with `Visibility="Collapsed"` to hide the element. Then I created a `ValueChanged` event on the object I wanted to multiply the value for. The event would update the hidden `Slider Value`.

This would allow me to bind the `Value` with the multiplied double to the desired object such as `Border` or `Button`.

Here is a working example.

```
<Window x:Class="WidthExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid Margin="10" MinWidth="500" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Ellipse Fill="#FFCD4B7A" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ElementName=mainSlider, Path=Value}" Height="{Binding ElementName=mainSlider, Path=Value}" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFCD6B19" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ElementName=hiddenWidthSlider, Path=Value}" Height="{Binding ElementName=hiddenHeightSlider, Path=Value}" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
            <Slider x:Name="mainSlider" Value="50" Minimum="10" Maximum="300" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="1" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="5" ValueChanged="mainSlider_ValueChanged" />
            <Slider x:Name="hiddenWidthSlider" Value="50" Minimum="1" Maximum="1000" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="1" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <Slider x:Name="hiddenHeightSlider" Value="50" Minimum="1" Maximum="1000" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="1" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WidthExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void mainSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            if (hiddenWidthSlider != null)
            {
                hiddenWidthSlider.Value = mainSlider.Value * 2;
            }
            if (hiddenHeightSlider != null)
            {
                hiddenHeightSlider.Value = mainSlider.Value / 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, The `Slider` controls the `Width` and `Height` of the circle. There are two hidden sliders that control the width and height of the `Rectangle`. The value of the circle is used to base the value of the rectangle.

In this case, the width of the rectangle is twice the width and half the height of the circle. I don't know if using a hidden element is the best solution, but it is an option.

Answer (score 3):

You can't bind a local variable.

Instead, you need to bind a property of some object:

```
someObject.SomeProperty = 42;
new Binding("SomeProperty", someObject)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more in the case of WidthProperty? `someBorder.Width= 42; new Binding("Width", someBorder)` Does not work.

Comment: @MiddleCSharp: It sounds like you want to set the property directly rather than using a binding.

Comment: I want to bind a value to a WidthProperty to see the change in real time. The value needs to be multiplied by `slider` value. I'm wondering if I can directly bind a double value rather than look for some converter.

Comment: @MiddleCSharp: That's not how binding works.  You can only bind to a property of an object.  Instead, you can add a property to your object that returns `SomeProperty * 100`.  (and make sure to raise `PropertyChanged` correctly.

Comment: I previously tried binding a hidden slider with value multiplied. But I can't convert a double to a windows slider value.

Comment: @MiddleCSharp: I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Is your intent to always multiply the bound source value by some constant?

- Then you may want to use an `IValueConverter` in your binding OR
- if you are writing a control code, define your border element as a template part and update the respective property of the template part with the multiplied value each time `WidthProperty` gets updated.

Otherwise, you could write

```
double changedNum = 3;
double myWidth = 100 * changedNum;
border1.SetBinding(WidthProperty, new Binding(".") { Source = myWidth });
```

Comment: @Benjamin IValueConverter is probably the answer. Yes, I want to multiply a value by another value that is not a constant. `new Binding(".")` does not work in this case.

Comment: @SLaks: I do not see the functional difference between your code and mine, except that you are referencing the value via a property (property path) instead of directly referencing the value itself. I double checked this and it works (at least in Silverlight, which is supposed to be subset of WPF). But as it turned out, that was not the solution of the actual problem.

Comment: @Benjamin: There is no point in making a binding to a local variable; he might as well set the property directly.  If he wants the binding to _update_, he'll need an object, a property, and an event.

Comment: @SLaks: I agree with you, that binding to a local variable does not make much sense in this case (and will not in most other cases). I just wanted to show how the code from the question could be just slightly altered so that the binding works _at all_ (knowing that this would be a one-time update)

Answer (score 0):

For Databinding to work, the binding target i.e the Property to which the value is bound needs to be a Dependency property and the binding source needs to be a class Property.

In the below code snippet

```
<Textbox Text="{Binding MyText}" ... />
```

The control Textbox has a dependency property called "TextProperty" and MyText has to be a class Property. The reason why MyText needs to be a class property is because behind the scenes WPF/Silverlight looks for the method `getMyText()` when reading the value to bind to and `setMyText()` when updating the value. For more information on how binding works behind the scenes I would recommend that one see the implementation of the Binding class in PresenationFramework.dll using dotPeek or some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

Just like SLacks answer but with anonymous types:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("SomeProperty");
binding.Source = new {SomeProperty = myLocalVariable};
```